# How do you set amperage in a simple circuit?

Tags: led, circuit-analysis, ohms-law

Volts = Amps * Ohms

Theoretically I wanted this (rounded):
3 V = 0.002 A * 1440 Ohms

Realistically I got this because a limit of resistors I had (rounded):
3.206 Volts = 0.002 Amps * 1421 Ohms

From this combination:
3.206 Volts (1.5V AA battery + another 1.5V in series) and 
1424 Resistance (1k resistor + 220 resistor + 220 resistor)

But this resulted in 8mA when I measure the first wire to the
last with a multi meter and 4mA directly on the LED instead 
of the mathematical 2.2561mA that I thought we should see. 
Why does this happen?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWkjBh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Use the NODE component to mark where you measured voltages. Use the ammeter symbol (down the bottom) to show where you measured the current. Are you by any chance shorting out components with your ammeter? (You shouldn't be.)

Comment: I've not worked much with schematics, but I tried to match my circuit with your descriptions. I am not shorting out any components, as far as I know.

Comment: If you connected your ammeter to A1 like you showed, then you shorted out the LED.  To measure current, you break the path and put the ammeter in series with your circuit.

Comment: Since you have a resistor with a nice round value (1k), measure the voltage across R3 and calculate the current from that.

Comment: It sounds like you measured two different currents...4mA and 8mA...at two different points in the circuit. That's not possible. There must be a problem with how you are making these measurements.

Comment: you cannot have `V1` at both ends of the battery ... if you do, then the battery is short-circuited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We take current measurements by connecting an ammeter (or a multimeter with the leads and range set to mA or A) in series with the load - not across the load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2focsTm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. AM1 shows the correct way to measure the current. Typically the voltage will be measured with respect to ground (usually battery negative) so you could measure V1, V2 and V3 to see increasing voltages with respect to ground.*

Note that we can also calculate the current if we know the voltage across a resistor of known value. In this case you have a 1 kΩ resistor and the voltage drop across that will be 1 V/mA. You should take a current reading (AM1) and a voltage reading (VM1) taking care to select the right probe sockets and range select before powering on the circuit. The current reading and calculated current should agree.

[image]

*Figure 2. IV curves for various colours of LED. Source: [LED IV curves](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/).*

To figure out the resistance required for an LED you can use the graph of Figure 2. Select the current you require, trace a line across to the colour of your LED and drop down to the voltage line to see what the forward-voltage, V<sub>f</sub> of the LED will be. You seem to be using 0.002 A or 2 mA for yours.

I'll choose 10 mA as it will be easier to read on the graph and I'm going to assume you have a green LED. Tracing across from 10 mA on the vertical axis we see that the grid line crosses the green curve at 2.0 V. That means your voltage-dropping resistors need to drop 1 V (since you have a 3 V supply). We then calculate \$ R = \frac V I = \frac 1 {0.01} = 100 \ \Omega \$.

Notice that at 2 mA the voltage will still be close to 2.0 V so you can revise the calculation to give \$ R = \frac V I = \frac 1 {0.002} = 500 \ \Omega \$. There's no need to be too exact with this circuit as your battery voltage is going to vary with state of charge.